# Arc Segment between two points and a radius

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I am trying to paint an arc segment using WPF, but I somehow cannot figure out how to do this using the ArcSegment-Element.

I have two points of the arc given (P1 and P2) and I also have the center of the circle and the radius.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a PathFigure with P1 as `StartPoint` and an ArcSegment with P2 as `Point` and a quadratic `Size` that contains the radius.

Example: P1 = (150,100), P2 = (50,50), Radius = 100, i.e. Size=(100,100):

```
<Path Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="150,100">
                <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="50,50"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

or shorter:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M150,100 A100,100 0 0 0 50,50"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a little old, but here goes a code version for a center and two angles - can be adapted to start and end points easily:

Outline:

- Make a path and set the "top left" to 0,0 (You can still have center be negative if you want - this is just for path reference)
- Set up the boiler plate PathGeo and PathFigure (these are building blocks of the multi-segment path in Word etc.)
- Do angle checking
- If it is > 180 deg (pi radians), call it a "large angle"
- Find begining and end points and set them
- Based upon the math, it is a clockwise rotation (remember that positive Y is down, positive X is right)
- Set to canvas

  ```
  public void DrawArc(ref Path arc_path, Vector center, double radius, double start_angle, double end_angle, Canvas canvas)
  {
      arc_path = new Path();
      arc_path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
      arc_path.StrokeThickness = 2;
      Canvas.SetLeft(arc_path, 0);
      Canvas.SetTop(arc_path, 0);

      start_angle = ((start_angle % (Math.PI * 2)) + Math.PI * 2) % (Math.PI * 2);
      end_angle = ((end_angle % (Math.PI * 2)) + Math.PI * 2) % (Math.PI * 2);
      if(end_angle < start_angle){
          double temp_angle = end_angle;
          end_angle = start_angle;
          start_angle = temp_angle;
      }
      double angle_diff = end_angle - start_angle;
      PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
      PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
      ArcSegment arcSegment = new ArcSegment();
      arcSegment.IsLargeArc = angle_diff >= Math.PI;
      //Set start of arc
      pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(start_angle), center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(start_angle));
      //set end point of arc.
      arcSegment.Point = new Point(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(end_angle), center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(end_angle));
      arcSegment.Size = new Size(radius, radius);
      arcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;

      pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);
      pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
      arc_path.Data = pathGeometry;
      canvas.Children.Add(arc_path);
  }
  ```